# Adsense Units of "Forbes" Magazine:: Frozen ADSENSE TERMS?

Tags: google-adsense

I was reading [Youngest Billionaires of 2013](http://www.forbes.com/pictures/eimh45gjid/the-youngest-billionaires-of-2013/) from Forbes Magazine, but surprised by seeing that they are using strange types of adsense unit in their posts. At first I thought that its done by adsense API, later I found that they did a iframe job to show **Search Result Ad**!

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Also, they show only adsense ads for few seconds for the first time you visit that website, this maybe sometime force the visitors to click those ads. Can any publisher do the same? isn't it breaking adsense terms?

Maybe I am wrong, what you are thinking? Is any publisher can do the same?

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be due to the fact that Forbes is a premium Adsense publisher. Conventional Adsense guidelines do not apply to them. They can choose their own ads, their own payment rates, and they even have their own ad manager.

Its not a discrimination. Anyone can become a premium publisher, as long as you generate the required amount of pages views each month.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you visit a link on Forbes using a back link your temporary redirected to a redirection page that has a continue button, i.e `http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome_mjx.shtml` this uses a cookie that once you continue you no longer get this redirection.

There is an obvious continue button at the top of the page, this is similar behavior to that of ad.fy, now its important to note that the 'big players' are sometimes overlooked when it comes to Google violations, This may not be tolerated for some, while others overlooked. You can check the terms and conditions yourself and use that as a footprint, do not look at what others are doing as I've said these rules may not apply to them, Google ***has the reserved right of negotiating different terms for larger sites***.

The iframe ad is a text only advert, I see nothing strange here and normally is how the Google forwards the ads using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, making sense,, but what i think is, Google should not play this kind of discrimination for Larger or Semi-Larger sites...

Comment: Sadly we live in the a corrupt world, follow the money and that's likely where your find most corruption ;)

Comment: We do live in a corrupt world, but IMO this is not an example of one. Custom deals are reserved for larger sites because they cost more to make and require more revenue to be profitable. If I make blue widgets and sell them to everyone but one customer asks for a red one, I probably can't. If a customer asks for 10000 red ones, then I'll probably order some red pigment and fill the lines with it.

Answer (score 0):

All publishers must adhere to the guidelines they have signed up for, including any updates to those guidelines. Violations may not be detected but when they are suspension from the program is the most likely consequence.

Large clients are able to get their own variant on terms-of-service simply because they have more to offer. You will sometimes see ads that are even more different than the ones you have seen and they are generated by adhering to a private agreement between Google and that particular client.